# Why do automatic properties require both getters AND setters?

Tags: c#, .net, automatic-properties

In C#, if I declare an auto-implemented property, why do I have to declare BOTH the get and set part?

i.e.

```
public string ThisWorks { get; set; }

public string ThisDoesnt { get; }
```

Isn't this just syntactic sugar - i.e. the compiler inserts a private field for the property?  So why the problem?

Curious.

Comment: Both works properly. I use them all the time.

Comment: But remember to add a type to the property. Your example won't work as it is now.

Comment: Oops, cheers!  But I'll have to take you to task on your claims - I get a compiler error, straight up.

Comment: @ALL: Thanks - that's one for the Book of Blindingly Obvious!  Because I was setting it in the constructor I was thinking along the lines of Jon Skeet, and missed the other cases.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you didn't have a setter - then how would you ever set the property?

Incidentally, you can specify the accessibility, eg:

```
public string Foo
{
  get;
  private set;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Without a setter, you would never be able to provide a value - as you don't have any way of specifying the backing variable's name.

I've requested a readonly automatic property, declared like this:

```
public string ReadonlyProperty { get; readonly set; }
```

which would create a readonly backing variable, a property with only a getter, and translate all calls to the setter into direct access to the variable. You could only call the setter within the constructor - just like for normal readonly variables.

We'll see whether this request does any good... it's a real shame it's not in there at the moment, as it makes it harder to implement immutable types than mutable types :(

Comment: What would this provide that: "public readonly string ReadonlyProperty" would not other than the ability to break point on accessing the property?

Comment: @ffpf - public readonly string Blah; <-- that's not a property, that's a field. You need a get/set to be a "property". Fields aren't picked up on things like databinding, property-grids, etc. They have a different semantic meaning.

Comment: See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx for why I don't like exposing public fields other than *sometimes* constants.

Comment: VB 10 might get this: "ReadOnly Property MaxItems As Integer = 100"

Comment: @jon: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I hadn't considered the serialization or ref points.

@Timothy: I understand the difference. That wasn't the point I was making in this instance. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

An auto-implemented property has no accessible private store, so you would have no way to set the value without a setter, making it totally useless.

Answer (score 3):

You need a set - otherwise, how does your auto-implemented property get its value? When auto-implementing the property, you have to have a set accessor to at least give it a value during construction.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, the new Roslyn compiler in Visual Studio 2015 now allows this, even if the project is configured to use C# version 5.